# Check if a GET method is Null/Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have recently been working with a `<select>` tag, however, I have noticed you cannot determine, using an `if statement` if the `GET` is `NULL` or equal to `""`.

```
    var tbl_st = (from c in db.tblfsk_style select c).ToArray();
    build.Append("<select id='style' name='style' class='styles'>");
    foreach (var style in tbl_st)
    {
        build.Append("<option value='" + style.StyleID + "'>" + style.Description + "</option>");
    }
    build.Append("</select>");
    if(Request.QueryString["style"] != "")
    {
        var choosen = Request.QueryString["style"];
        var tbl_colour = (from c in db.tblfsk_style_colour where c.StyleID == choosen select c).ToArray();
        build.Append("<select id='colour' name='colour' class='styles'>");
        foreach (var colour in tbl_colour)
        {
           build.Append("<option value='" + colour.ColourID + "'>" + colour.ColourID + "</option>");
        }
        build.Append("</select>");
    }
    build.Append("<button type='submit' class='btn'>Continue</button>");
```

The idea is when they choose `Continue` as a `Button` the next thing loads up but I am struggling to find a way to check if the `style` is null or not.

I have tried:

```
if(Request.QueryString["style"] != "") { // next <select> tag
```

And:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["style"])) { // next <select> tag
```

Is there a way to determine if the `style` is `null` in the `GET`?

PHP example of doing this (to explain better):

```
if(isset($_GET['style'])) { // next <select> tag
```

Comment: Style changes like this, which is what I assume you are trying to do, would be much easier to handle client side using JavaScript (see [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)).

Comment: Is style.StyleID a string type and is it empty for "Continue"?

Comment: Continue is a button @JamesDev When its clicked, I want to load another `<select>` tag which pulls **more** data out the database and puts it into the new `<select>` tag but if `style` is `NULL` I don't want it to pull the second thing out because its query is dependent on the `style` value.

Comment: The code you've shown *is* the right way to determine if your "style" value is null.  Something you've left out of the question is causing your problem.  Could you add both of your service methods in your question?  That would help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I'll edit that now @Brian

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by trying using the `try` and `catch` method.

```
try
{
    var sty_in = Request.QueryString["style"].ToString();
    build.Append("test");
}
catch(Exception)
{
    var tbl_st = (from c in db.tblfsk_style select c).ToArray();
    build.Append("<select id='style' name='style' class='styles'>");
    foreach (var style in tbl_st)
    {
        build.Append("<option value='" + style.StyleID + "'>" + style.Description + "</option>");
    }
    build.Append("</select>");
}
```

So if it has been inputted, we can replace `test` with putting our new `<select>` statement.

Or even easier:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["style"].ToString())){ }
```

Or

```
if(Request.QueryString["style"].ToString() != null) { }
```

I was missing the `ToString()`

Answer (score -1):

You are using Request.QueryString so the value should be passed through the URL as a GET parameter. You can easily see the value of style if it is passed correctly through the URL string.

Comment: Yes but when I do: `if(Request.QueryString["style"] != "") { var styleChoosen = Request.QueryString["style"]; var tbl_next = (from c in db.tblfsk_colour where c.StyleID == styleChoosen select c).ToArray();` and output the colours to the new `<select>` it ignores the if statement and a empty `<select>` box is shown.... I asked how to check if its `NULL`

Comment: Why not debug and find the exact value of Request.QueryString["style"] at that point in a watch value? Is the value equal to "".

Comment: Because when I press continue it works, but `style` is never `NULL`. It just isn't set, so I am asking if you can check, like `PHP`, if it is `isset`

Comment: You mean you want to know if the user has not selected any value? In that case you need to have an empty first option value in your dropdown. That is the only way that Request.QueryString["style"] != ""